# Calculating rate of change of thermal energy and applying that to usage in calculating the time it takes to reach equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

So if I have an experiment with two gases that are identical and have a specific heat of 100 j/(KM) and there is a divider in between the gases with a surface area of 1 square meter, and a thickness of 1/3 of a meter and a temperature exchange constant of .5, how would I calculate how long it takes to reach equilibrium and what the temperature at any given time for the two gases is? also how would it change if the gases were non identical (IE different volume, moles, specific heat)

Comment: What is your assessment so far?  What are the units of that temperature exchange coefficient?

Comment: @ChesterMiller I know that the rate of change of temperature is kA(H-C)/d where k is the exchange coefficent, A is surface area, depth of the divider and H is the hot temperature, and c is the cold, the exchange coefficent is in W/mK

Comment: That is not the rate of change of temperature.  It is the rate of heat flow from the hot gas to the cold gas (leaving out the heat exchange coefficient effect).